# Ошибка подгрузки SonataMediaBundle, как быть?

Tags: symfony2, sonata

> Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "ApplicationSonataMediaBundle" from namespace "Application\Sonata\MediaBundle".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /home/den/mediablog.com/app/AppKernel.php:27

При этом Bundle есть, созданный как в документации `php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle`
кеш чистил, composer обновлял, почему он не может подгрузить не пойму.

Comment: Так надо по доке в AppKernal  `new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle()` а Вы, как я понял, делаете ApplicationSonataMediaBundle

Comment: По документации подключается  new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle() и  new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle()